# Powershell FileSystemWatcher script firing twice on some new files

Tags: powershell, filesystemwatcher

I'm using FileSystemWatcher to monitor a folder where documents are scanned to. When a new file is detected, it will send an email to notify someone. It's working as is, but sometimes (not every file) it will trigger 2 or 3 times on a new file and send the email 2-3 times for the same file. I'm guessing it has to do with the way the file is created by the scanner or something like that.

I'm trying to figure out a way to protect against this happening, to ensure it only sends one email per file. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
$PathToMonitor = "\\path\to\folder"

$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.Filter  = "*.*"
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false

$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true

$Action = {
    if ($EventArgs.Name -notlike "*.pdf" -and $EventArgs.Name -notlike "*.tif") {
        return
    }
        $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
        $Name = $details.Name
        $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
        $text = "{0} was submitted on {1}." -f $Name, $Timestamp
        
        $FromAddress = "Email1 <email1@email.com>"
        $ToAddress = "Email2 <Email2@email.com>"
        $Subject = "New File"
        $SMTPserver = "123.4.5.678"
    
        Send-MailMessage -From $FromAddress -To $ToAddress -Subject $Subject -Body $text -SmtpServer $SMTPserver
    
}

$handlers = . {
    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $FileSystemWatcher -EventName Created -Action $Action -SourceIdentifier FSCreateConsumer
}

try {
    do {
        Wait-Event -Timeout 5
    } while ($true)
}
finally {
    Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier FSCreateConsumer
    
    $handlers | Remove-Job
    
    $FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $false
    $FileSystemWatcher.Dispose()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be because you listen too many [notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher.notifyfilter?view=net-6.0). The default is `LastWrite`, `FileName`, and `DirectoryName`
`FileName` is sufficient for your need and may prevent your issue.

```
$FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName
```

As a remark, I don't know why you use `Wait-Event -Timeout 5`. Script is working fine without the `try{}` block.

**EDIT: Add a ConcurrentDictionary to avoid duplicate events**

Try this sample code. I've included only the beginning part of your script. End is untouched.

```
$PathToMonitor = "\\path\to\folder"
$KeepFiles = 5  #minutes

$MonitoredFiles = New-Object -TypeName 'System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary[[System.String],[System.DateTime]]'

$FileSystemWatcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$FileSystemWatcher.Path  = $PathToMonitor
$FileSystemWatcher.Filter  = "*.*"
$FileSystemWatcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $false
$FileSystemWatcher.NotifyFilter = [System.IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName

$FileSystemWatcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true


$Action = {
    if ($EventArgs.Name -notlike "*.pdf" -and $EventArgs.Name -notlike "*.tif") {
        return
    }

    #Cleaning events -gt 5mn
    $Now = [System.DateTime]::Now
    $OriginEventDate = [System.DateTime]::MinValue
    foreach($MonitoredFile in [System.Linq.Enumerable]::ToList(($MonitoredFiles.Keys))) {
        if ($MonitoredFiles.TryGetValue($MonitoredFile, [ref]$OriginEventDate)) {
            if ($OriginEventDate.AddMinutes($KeepFiles) -gt $Now) {
                try {
                    [void]$MonitoredFiles.Remove($MonitoredFile)
                } 
                catch {}
            }
        }
    }

    $ProcessEvent = $false
    # any same file creation event within 5mn are discarded
    $OriginEventDate = [System.DateTime]::MinValue
    if ($MonitoredFiles.TryGetValue($event.SourceEventArgs.Name, [ref]$OriginEventDate)) {
        if ($OriginEventDate -ne [System.DateTime]::MinValue -and $OriginEventDate.AddMinutes($KeepFiles) -le $Now) {
            return
        }
        else {
            $ProcessEvent = $true
        }
    }
    else {
        #not successful means a concurrent event was successful, so discard this one.
        if ($MonitoredFiles.TryAdd($event.SourceEventArgs.Name, $event.SourceEventArgs.TimeGenerated)) {
            $ProcessEvent = $true
        }
        else {
            return
        }
    }

    
    if ($ProcessEvent) {
            
        $details = $event.SourceEventArgs
        $Name = $details.Name
        $Timestamp = $event.TimeGenerated
        $text = "{0} was submitted on {1}." -f $Name, $Timestamp
        
        $FromAddress = "Email1 <email1@email.com>"
        $ToAddress = "Email2 <Email2@email.com>"
        $Subject = "New File"
        $SMTPserver = "123.4.5.678"
    
        Send-MailMessage -From $FromAddress -To $ToAddress -Subject $Subject -Body $text -SmtpServer $SMTPserver
    }
}
```

Comment: It's my understanding the try block with wait-event is to make it asynchronous, so that if multiple events come in it will queue them up and handle each one. Otherwise you could potentially miss events. As covered here: https://powershell.one/tricks/filesystem/filesystemwatcher

Comment: Thanks for the link, interesting.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added the notifyfilter and will monitor for a bit and see if that helps.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not seem to have resolved it. :(

Comment: As an alternate solution you could use a Dictionary / HashTable to store the filename and a timestamp so you can on any event check if the filename is in the dictionary and if the timestamp last happened in less than last 5 minutes you discard the event, else you send the mail as usual.

Comment: I was thinking of trying something like this, but I'm new to powershell so will have to work through it. Should I be concerned with clearing things out of the hashtable at some point so it doesn't accrue records endlessly?

Comment: I've added an edit to my initial answer.

Comment: Cool idea, I think this will work. Thanks! Marking as answer.

Comment: I spoke too soon. Nothing happens when I drop in a file. I'm trying to diagnose where the problem might be but no luck yet.

Comment: You can run it in debug mode on a test folder, inserting a breakpoint inside the Action scriptblock, and dropping files within the folder. If I have some time I'll try on my side.

Comment: I think the the -le and -gt locations should be reversed in your code.

Answer (score 1):

I had to adjust these two things to make it work:

```
if ($MonitoredFiles.TryAdd($Event.SourceEventArgs.Name, $Event.TimeGenerated))

if ($OriginEventDate -ne [System.DateTime]::MinValue -and $OriginEventDate.AddMinutes($KeepFiles) -ge $Now)
```

Answer (score 1):

My case was simpler, just wanted to avoid processing an event with same timestamp.
I used a global variable like

```
$global:lastTimestamp = "empty"

...

$currTimestamp = $Event.TimeGenerated.toString()

if ($lastTimestamp -ne $currTimestamp) {
    ... do actions
}

$lastTimestamp = $currTimestamp
```